# Construct Subgroups of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> How can I construct subgroups of $G \times H$, where $G = H = (\mathbb{Z}, +)$?

I thought that the only subgroups of the integers where the integers times some constant, but then I don't know how to prove that, and even if I did I don't know if that applies to this situation.

Comment: To begin with, make a list of all the subgroups of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ that you can think of.

Comment: Your problem statement is a bit ambiguous. One might interpret it as asking for all possible subgroups of $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$, which is a bit harder than just finding a few examples of them. Pieces of information like "I need five examples of blah" are things you shouldn't refrain from telling readers.

Answer (score 1):

One sure way to find subgroups of any group is to pick an element and see what it generates. It will always generate for your a cyclic subgroup (and in fact this is a pretty good way of finding all cyclic subgroups of a given group). This will give you more and more examples of cyclic subgroups and might give you some ideas of how to find more subgroups, or how to prove there aren't any. Experiment with the group!

Comment: So if the only subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are $n\mathbb{Z}$, then I only see four subgroups, if we count the identity as being something different. I was asked for five. Should I just pick five pairings?

Comment: @Tony Only four subgroups? There are much more than four natural numbers...